# SSDT building error saying "unresolved reference to Login"

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, visual-studio-2015

We retrieved source code from a SQL Server 2016 database and made a Visual Studio 2015 SSDT (SQL Server Data Tool) project. The source code contains a file `Security\foglight5.sql` with the below content:

```sql
CREATE USER [foglight5] FOR LOGIN [foglight5];
```

We want to deploy the source code on a testing instance of SQL Server, so that we have a development environment with the same DDL as the server.

However, when trying to publish the source code to a testing instance, Visual Studio requires building first. And, when building the project, we got an error saying `Error     SQL71501: User: [foglight5] has an unresolved reference to Login [foglight5].`.

**Our Question:**

How to resolve the above error and proceed with our testing deployment?

Comment: Do you want to create the user (and login) in your test deployment or do you want to ignore the user?

Comment: Ignoring the user is OK for me.